# Dojo _TemplatedMixin: changing templateString

Tags: dojo

How do I change the template of a widget, using mixins `dijit/_TemplatedMixin` and `dijit/_WidgetsInTemplateMixin`, at a later time (not in the constructor)?

My scenario is that the widget must make a call to the server to get data, and the callback function will then merge the data with a template file and then the resulting template should be used for the `templateString`.  The widget should update its contents at this point.

Setting the templateString and calling buildRendering() has no effect.
Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
define([
    "dojo/_base/declare", 
    "dojo/_base/lang",
    "dijit/_WidgetBase",
    "dijit/_TemplatedMixin",
    "dijit/_WidgetsInTemplateMixin",
    ],
function(declare, lang, _WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin) {
    return declare([_WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin], {
        constructor: function(id) {
            this.id = id;
            this.templateString = "<div>Loading...</div>";
            //use xhr to call REST service to get data.
            //dataLoadedCallback is executed with response data
            ...
        },

        dataLoadedCallback : function(data) {
            this.destroyRendering();
            //render a templateString using the data response from the rest call
            this.templateString = "<div>Data is loaded. Name:" + data.name + "</div>"
            this.buildRendering();
        },
    });
});
```

Comment: Instead of trying to set the templateString couldn't you just add the callback content to some part of the widget's dom?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do such thing. The template is parsed only once before `postCreate` method.

However there is few things you can do:

- Create a non-ui widget which will do the XHR call. When this non-ui widget get the XHR response it creates the UI widget with the correct `templateString`
- Or use `dojo/dom-construct`. It contains a `toDom` method which you can use for converting your string into nodes. Then you can append that to the widget.
  Note: this will not parse any `data-dojo` attributes
- You could also directly inject the received templateString into the widget domNode:

  `dataLoadedCallback : function(data) {
     this.domNode.innerHTML = "<div>Data is loaded. Name:" + data.name + "</div>";
     //you might be able to parse the content (if you have subwidgets) using dojo/parse
  },`

Last but not least, here is a util I wrote for my self. It allow to parse any `templateString` at any time (like dojo does on widget creation)

```js
define([
 'dojo/dom-construct',
 'dojo/string',

 'dijit/_AttachMixin',
 'dijit/_TemplatedMixin'
], function(domConstruct, string,
  _AttachMixin, _TemplatedMixin) {

 // summary:
 //  provide an utility to parse a template a runtime (and create attach point, atach events, etc...)
 //  Copyright: Benjamin Santalucia

 var GET_ATTRIBUTE_FUNCTION = function(n, p) { return n.getAttribute(p); },
  _TemplateParserMixin = function() {};

 _TemplateParserMixin.prototype = {
  parseTemplate: function(template, data, container, position, transformer) {
   // summary:
   //  parse the template exactly as dojo will nativly do with a templateString
   if(this._attachPoints === undefined) {
    this._attachPoints = [];
   }
   if(this._attachEvents === undefined) {
    this._attachEvents = [];
   }

   var nodes,
    x,
    len,
    newTemplate = string.substitute(template, data, transformer),
    node = domConstruct.toDom(_TemplatedMixin.prototype._stringRepl.call(this, newTemplate));
   if(node.nodeName === '#document-fragment') {
    node = node.firstChild;
   }

   //parse all nodes and create attach points and attach events
   nodes = node.getElementsByTagName('*');
   len = nodes.length;
   for(x = -1; x < len; x++) {
    _AttachMixin.prototype._processTemplateNode.call(this, x < 0 ? node : nodes[x], GET_ATTRIBUTE_FUNCTION, _AttachMixin.prototype._attach);
   }

   if(container) {
    domConstruct.place(node, container, position);
   }

   return node;
  }
 };
 return _TemplateParserMixin;
});
```

Usage is:

```
returnedNode = w.parseTemplate(newTemplateString, {
            templatePlaceHolderName: 'foo' //for teplate with placeholders like ${templatePlaceHolderName}
}, domNodeToInsertIn, 'only'); //last parameter is same as dojo/dom-construct::place() >> last, first, before, after, only
```